# Custom Destructors with Placement New

Tags: c++, memory, memory-management

I have an object that I allocate using [placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/placement-new.html). When the object is not needed anymore I use its destructor explicitly, then take care of the memory myself, as described in various sources on the web.
It is not clear to me however if the compiler may generate any additional 'magic in the background' for the destructor call, other than just generating instructions for what's inside the destructor. The actual question is: Would anything prevent me from using 'custom destructors' instead of the regular (~ syntax) destructors in the case of 'placement-new'? Simple class methods that contain all the usual destructor code but may additionally take arguments.
Here is an example:

```
class FooBar {
  FooBar() { ... }
  ...
  void myCustomDestructor(int withArguments) { ... }
  ...
};

int main() {
  ...
  FooBar* obj = new (someAddress) FooBar();
  ...
  obj->~FooBar();  // <- You're supposed to do this.
  obj->myCustomDestructor(5);  // <- But can you do this instead?
  ...
  // Then do whatever with the memory at someAddress...
}
```

Any disadvantages going with custom destructors?

Comment: I don't think you have a choice there. If the destructor has side effects, then it's UB to not call it before you reuse or free the memory, no matter what you do in your own function. And if the destructor has no effects, then your own function isn't really a "destructor" and just another function.

Comment: Summary: Yes, sometimes there is compiler magic in destructors.  Namely, it calls the destructors of all members and parent objects.

Comment: @KerrekSB That was actually my question: If destructors are really just class methods. I am aware myCustomDestructor() does not get called through the usual operator delete nor if the object is allocated locally and goes out of scope. But that discussion would be already out of the question scope.

Comment: @MooingDuck you're right, members would not get destructed automatically. In the given example, just assume there are no members with nontrivial destructors.

Comment: What exactly does your custom destructor do?  What's stopping you from simply calling it, and then calling the normal destructor?  If the members all have trivial destructors, it costs you nothing and you get no undefined behavior.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley I guess that is the correct way to go.

Answer (score 1):

While this is technically be possible, I recommend against it.

Destructors are there for a reason: The compiler takes care of calling the destructors of all base classes. If you use your custom destructor, you need to take care of that yourself (and are likely to forget it somewhere).

Additionally, using a different method than the default destructor will be all but obvious to anyone reading your code.

What advantages do you expect from using a custom destructor? I don't see any.

Comment: A custom destructor can take arguments.  If a normal destructor needs arguments, you have to add them as permanent members of the class, which is absurd as a solution.  (And yes, I have run into this situation in real code)

Comment: If you want a specific example, I wrote wrappers for JNI objects, but had to have a pointer to the JNI "environment" to release the objects.

Comment: The advantage would be being able to use parameters for the destructor.

Comment: What about Exception handling? The compiler doesn't know about the parameters you want to pass to the object destructor.
This would lead to unmaintainable code.
If you need a seperate release-method with parameters, provide one and call it before calling the actual destructor.

Answer (score 1):

The "extra magic" is that the object ceases to exist only after the destructor is called. So you can't reuse the memory after calling `myCustomDestructor` since the object "still exists", well, at least not without undefined behavior.

One solution is to make a private destructor and do something like this:

```
class FooBar {
  public:
    FooBar() { ... }
    static void destruct(FooBar& foobar, int withArguments) {
       foobar.myCustomDestructor(withArguments);
       foobar.~FooBar();
    }
  private:
    void myCustomDestructor(int withArguments) { ... }
    ~FooBar() {}
};

int main() {
  ...
  FooBar* obj = new (someAddress) FooBar();

  FooBar::destruct(*obj, 5);

  // Then do whatever with the memory at someAddress...
}
```

This calls both the custom "destructor" and the actual destructor, thus telling the compiler the object now ceases to exist.

Comment: Well that's clever. but confusing.  Since you can't have a local `FooBar`, nor can you ever call `delete` on it.

Comment: Sure an object behaves weird if I write over its storage. But it wouldn't affect anything else than the object or cause any other undefined behavior, would it? Hence I don't understand the term "ceases to exist".

Comment: @RafaelSpring It's definitely undefined behavior, meaning anything could happen, but you're probably right that in this case nothing will go wrong. Still, I wouldn't risk it.

Answer (score 1):

No, you can't do that without undefined behavior.  I would just do this instead:

```
void FooBar::prepareForCustomDestruction(int arguments)
{
    do_custom_destruction = true;
    custom_destructor_arguments = arguments;
}

FooBar::~FooBar()
{
    if (do_custom_destruction)
    {
        // custom destruction
    }
    else
    {
        // normal destruction
    }
}
```

Then if you want to simulate calling a custom destructor, just call `prepareForCustomDestruction` first.

```
obj->prepareForCustomDestuction(5);
obj->~FooBar();
```

Comment: Or, since `custom_destructor_arguments` would have to be a member, initialize them in the constructor like normal members. (maybe with a setter if needed)  Then you also have no need of `do_custom_destruction` nor the `if`.

Comment: I thought about this solution at first but decided against it since it would necessitate at least one other class member which is prohibitive in memory for my use case.

Comment: @MooingDuck: My assumption here is that the decision of whether or not to do the custom destruction is not made until sometime later in the object's lifetime.